# Failed to import Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, python-import, importerror

I am trying to build a recommender system with Python. However, I can't proceed since I get an import error of Sklearn everytime.

I get this error:

> "ImportError: DLL load failed: Can't find module."

How do i fix this? (The last sentence in the error is in Dutch btw)

A screenshot of my error is below.

By the way: I get the same import error for Seaborn

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 + Visual Studio Code - "CMD + SHIFT + P" from within visual studio code and search for "Select Interpreter" clicking on this will show a list of available python interpreters and versions installed on your system that are detected by visual studio code and your currently selected environment.  (Visual Studio Code usually incorrectly defaults to 32 bit interpreter)

Ensure you have the correct python environment (where you have the required libraries & "packages" installed)

This should fix  your import issue if you have the libraries installed.  Use the appropriate cmd line tool to install packages.  If you are using Anaconda - use Conda Install or use pip etc...

Answer (score 0):

`Scikit-learn` uses `numpy` and `scipy`. Those modules are using C and Fortran code that needs to be compiled. Nonetheless, Windows cannot compile them right away.

I would recommend you to download  [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) and install scikit-learn like [this](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scikit-learn). (You may need to add conda to path)

Another method is to download precompiled binary from [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn). Then run:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
pip install <numpy-wheel>
pip install <scipy-wheel>
pip install <scikit-wheel>
```